# Can knockout.js bind to CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, refactoring

Suppose I have a large JS file full of definitions like:

```
$(document).on('focusin', '.field', function () {
    // some logic
}).on('focusout', '.field', function () {
    // some logic
});
```

In the places where the selector refers to an `#element`, I can easily refactor it into a knockout viewModel - I simply add a `data-bind` attribute for the action on the element, and move the logic into the viewModel.
But in those "CSS bound events" wiring situations, I can't see how it could be done....

**What is the common / recommended practice here? Should I leave this be beside my shiny knockout code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom binding provider to use Knockout bindings without having to define `data-bind` attributes. Here are some examples and further info:

- http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html
- http://jsfiddle.net/StevenSanderson/n7h2A/1/
- [Unobtrusive Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13451414/1287183)
- https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-classBindingProvider
- https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I do things like that creating custom bindings.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Look at the example with focus:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hasFocus = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if(element.hasClass('yourClass') {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value(true);
        }          
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value))
            element.attr('class', 'somethingElse');
        else
            element.toggleClass('somethingToToggle');
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not asking about focus or hover. I don't have an element to bind to with the custom binding, so it won't help.

Comment: There is no one "the element"... There could be 42 elements with that class, and it wouldn't make sense adding data-bind on all of them!

Comment: Look at my edit. Now it control bindings depending on classes.

Comment: ko work in this way... adding data-bindings... You can use a template if you don't wont to repeat code...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine and maybe your question is more towards how to organize your code. If so, I'd recommend checking out this [code sample from tekpub](https://github.com/tekpub/mvcmusic/tree/master/MvcMusicStore/assets/js), and see how Rob Conery structured his app.

Essentially, he's using namespaces to encapsulate knockout-related code and using the same pattern for encapsulating wiring up of events.

The files I would look into are application.js, order_editor.js, and [this html file](https://github.com/tekpub/mvcmusic/blob/master/MvcMusicStore/views/Orders/Edit.cshtml) where he instantiates his stuff.

You can also get fancier by using something like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org) to load things as you need them.