# Is Knockout.js inline with content/UI/behavior separation best practices?

Tags: html, knockout.js, code-separation

I've been working on the web for quite a long time and I saw the "best practices" evolve. I'm now fairly convinced separating HTML (Content), Javascript (Behavior) and CSS (UI) is the best thing to do.

A few months ago, I started using knockout.js . I did choose it among other similar frameworks like backbone or angular because a chapter in an MVC training I followed was about knockout, and the concept seduced me. Then after a quick comparison on the web it didn't look as a bad choice for my needs, and for a start.

But here's my problem : when I look at my HTML code now, after a few weeks of dev on a project, there's quite a lot of knockout bindings in it, and it makes me think a lot about the old times, when we (or at least I) used to put inline javascript event handling through `onclick` attribute and so on.

Therefore those 2 questions, which I'm not sure are 100% suited for SO, but I can't find any better StackExchange site to ask it :

1. Is using knockout (or the other frameworks as they all seem to basically work with the same pattern) contrary to the "separation rule" ? Or is it an acceptable small-step-out of this rule ? or is it even perfectly acceptable because it uses the "data-" attributes ?
2. In the case this would be a somehow bad practice, is there any possibility to do all the binding through a separate javascript file, using for example jQuery to select the controls and apply bindings to them ? If not possible in knockout, is it with another framework ? I must admit at the time I did my selection, I diddn't think about this kind of implications...

Thank you and sorry if this should be moved to another SE site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unobtrusive Knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451414/unobtrusive-knockout)

Comment: I must not have searched on good terms before posting this question, cause now that I used other keywords (found in the answers here) to do my research, I realize that a lot of people have the same concerns, and some of them came together with solutions to it. So I flagged my own question as duplicate of a similar one with already very interesting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same initial reservations as you, but I have to say that having the bindings in the html and not hidden away in a JS file seems so much better to me, as the link between presentation and functionality is now completely obvious. It massively reduces the possibility of changing some HTML and breaking functionality because you weren't aware that someone had hooked up some javascript to an element using jQuery.

Also, as you point out, the use of the data-bind attribute does, I think, mean that it does adhere to the separation rule, though if you want to stick to it rigidly then make sure all bindings are to observables, computed or functions on your view model, don't use any code (i.e. a visible binding that checks the state of two observables). I'm not sure I'd take it that far though.

Comment: Thanks for this opinion. I agree with you on all points, but still. Sometimes, a simple inline `onclick` would lso be easier, and yet I put it outside, only because it's a best practice.
Regarding your other remark, I did think about it during the dev and had to choose. I chose to put the code in the binding self though (=> test the 2 observables) instead of a computed/observable beacuse I didn't want to "pollute" my ViewModel with that kind of stuff. And as the HTML was already "polluted", I decided to keep it there and let my viewmodel as light as can be.

Answer (score 1):

I guess everyone started to learn KnockoutJS have the same concerns.

IMHO, there must be some way that connects models(JS object) with views(HTML markup). Then we should have something that says:"When that button is clicked call this function with that arguments." or "Hide this element while you that JS array is empty" and so on. So how we can put/say/state that connection in a readable, reusable and clean way.

If you used another JS file to handle that connection, then you 'll have large lines of code just to put your connection logic and you need to know how to select the DOM element you are targeting. You 'll end up with massive code(probably lot of jQuery) just to make your HTML dynamic and *alive*(i bet most developers got into that many times). I haven't use other libraries or frameworks but i think they just make your massive code more organized.

On the other hand by KnockoutJS use `Declarative Bindings`, this is the link between models and views. It's more readable, easy to plug it in/out and it allow you to just focus on writing a good JS model object.

I guess to truly check separation think what if you sometime needed to change your model, how much changes you need to do to your view? and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the rest of the answers, some tips:

Make sure there's no business logic in your bindings. Any logic (which should be minimal) should be "view logic": decisions that only affect how your view *looks*, not how it *works*. Deciding how many items to display per screen is view logic; deciding whether the user can add another item is business logic. It's perfectly OK to put view logic in your viewmodel rather than your view, and it's desirable if it involves lengthy expressions.

Keep "magic numbers" out of any view logic in your bindings. If it's a parameter that could be changed (e.g. number of weeks of results to show) as opposed to a true constant (e.g. number of days in a week), make it a property of your viewmodel and reference it in any expressions in your views.